# MS Access: Why is my combo box displaying the wrong value?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have 2 columns that populate my combo box. They come from a table where I manually wrote in an `ID` and a `clean_value` field.

**The goal:**

Display both columns on a combo box on a form. The `ID` values should be on the **left** of the `clean_value` values when looking at the drop down list. When selecting something in the list, the combo box should display the `clean_value`, not the `ID`. When saving the form, the form should write the `ID` value to a different table.

**What I've tried:**

I set up the table to get the values from. I set up the combo box to show the 2 values in the correct orientation. The `ID` value is the value that is being written to the table.

**The problem:** When the user selects one of the values in the list, their selection shows the `ID`. I want to display the `clean_value` upon selection instead. How do I do this?

Comment: Change orientation of the fields. First `clean_value` , second `ID` and set `bound column` to 2.

Comment: @BitAccesser is there no way to keep the `ID` column on the left?

Comment: You can change the size of the columns in `Column Widths`. Set first to 0 (they are separated with `;`) and change `Column Count` to 2.

Comment: @BitAccesser Wait but I don't want either one to have a size of zero. I want them to both be shown in the drop down, but when the user selects a value then it should show the `clean_value` after clicking.

Comment: Sorry, missed that! So set widths to your desired values  > 0 (e.g.: 0.2";0.7875").

Comment: It's ok. So now how do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114252/discussion-between-bitaccesser-and-whatwhatwhat).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. I grabbed the `clean_value` field, the `ID` field, then the `clean_value` field again in the row source, then I just set the width of the first `clean_value` field to 0.021".

Comment: Be aware  to set the first fields width > 0 (as whatwhatwhat did). If set to exact 0 the second field of the `Row Source` is displayed (if width > 0).